# Searching in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

I’m having trouble searching in Thunderbird.

I’m reading [the help](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/global-search) and it isn’t clear to me what happens when you search for a special character.

How might one search for the word “D-Link” for example? Results I’m getting for that phrase are returning many emails with the word “link” in it.

Comment: Interesting thing is that this happens at least for me if I have any two characters followed by a space and then link all in quotes. Thus "xx link" does not work (ie returns results for "link", where as "xxx link" works. Granted, a little different from the special character issue.